# Strikeout li element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I wonder how to make a strikeout line over a `<li>` element. It needs to has specific height, same as the line before.  I attached an image of the menu's project.

I used li:before to make a dash, but I do not know how to figure out strikeout line over it.

[image]

Comment: Make a line long enough to cover the label

Comment: When is the strikeout is supposed to be over the whole item? On mouse hover?

Comment: @PierreLeBot The line will indicate on which subpage you are currently located. The line is an extension of a hyphen/dash.

Comment: Okay, then I think the answer I provided should work. Don't forget to mark it as _accepted_

Answer (score 1):

This should work. I choose to put the line-through on a specific element by adding the `active` CSS class, but that also could be on hover, focus or whatever.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 200px; /* for demo purpose only */
}

li {
    padding-left: 50px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 30px; /* for demo purpose only */
}

li:before {
    content: '';
    height: 4px;
    background-color: black;
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    /* fix alignment by upping the position of the strikeout by 50% of its height */
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

li.active:before {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="footer">
    <li>projects</li>
    <li class="active">books</li>
    <li>news</li>
    <li>about</li>
    <li>contact</li>
</ul>
```